# What is the best way to reorder an array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, key

Here is an array:

```
$array = (0 => "pear", 1 => "apple", 2 => "orange", 3 => "kiwi");
```

What is the best way to reorder the array to become:

```
$array = (0 => "pear", 1 => "kiwi", 2 => "orange", 3 => "apple");
```

---

***Edit:***

Please note I am **not** looking for an alphabetical sort.  I am looking to switch the order of two items within an array. My initial thought was to pop out the key=>value pair that I want to change, then reinsert it.  But I want to know if there is a better way.

Comment: [Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1673259/sort-array-by-value-alphabetically-php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1673259/sort-array-by-value-alphabetically-php)

Comment: Start by looking at sort() and asort()
Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1673259/sort-array-by-value-alphabetically-php
-or - are you really trying to change the keys?

Comment: Sorry guys, I noticed that it looked like I wanted a sort.  That was not actually my intention. I need to switch the order of two items in an array. It has nothing to do with the key's value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this code to switch 2 values of your array:

```
$tmp = $array[1];
$array[1] = $array[3];
$array[3] = $tmp;
unset($tmp); // you may delete the variable if you no longer need it
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use [`asort`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php) to sort your array alphabetically

General example

```
$fruits = array("d" => "lemon", "a" => "orange", "b" => "banana", "c" => "apple");
asort($fruits);
foreach ($fruits as $key => $val) {
    echo "$key = $val\n";
}
```

This will output

```
c = apple
b = banana
d = lemon
a = orange
```

Comment: Sorry, alphabetical was not my intention.  I will reword my question.

Answer (score 0):

Use `asort($array)` to sort an array.

Answer (score 0):

I would simply use:

```
$list = array('apple', 'pear', 'kiwi');
sort($list);
var_dump($list);
```

This is imho the best for not associative arrays.