# Sort single dimensional array & keep keys & values relation

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have a array both `key` & `value` are `string` like

```
 $myArr = array(
     'ball'=>'zebra', 
     'tree'=>'plant', 
     'zoo'=>'animal' );
```

I need to `sort array` by its `values` and keep `key`, `value` association, so output would be like

```
 $sortedArr = array(
     'zoo'=>'animal', 
     'tree'=>'plant', 
     'ball'=>'zebra' );
```

I am looking for shortest and smartest solution to achieve this, if you have that one please share with me.

Comment: has answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1673259/sort-array-by-value-alphabetically-php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at **asort**:

```
$myArr = array('ball'=>'zebra', 'tree'=>'plant', 'zoo'=>'animal');
asort($myArr);

echo print_r($myArr, TRUE);
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [zoo] => animal
    [tree] => plant
    [ball] => zebra
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Ramesh, you can also try this one.

```
function csort($a, $b) {
if ($a == $b) {
    return 0;
}
return ($a < $b) ? -1 : 1;
}
$myArr = array('ball'=>'zebra', 'tree'=>'plant', 'zoo'=>'animal');
uasort($myArr, 'csort');
print_r($myArr);
exit;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use any on the inbuilt php function listed here 
http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php

The all sorts by value and maintain key association

Answer (score 0):

I found solution.

```
asort($myArr);
```