# Alphabetically sort keys which has same value

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have an array that I have already sorted with `arsort` so that the value with the highest integer is shown first and the lowest integer shows last

My problem now is that I need to sort the keys alphabetically, but still retain my sort order by value. I have tried to sort the keys alphabetically using `krsort` before I sort by value with `arsort`, but this still gives me same output

This is how my original array looked like before applying `array_count_values` to it

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  string(7) "Romance"
  [1]=>
  string(7) "Romance"
  [2]=>
  string(7) "Classic"
  [3]=>
  string(6) "Comedy"
  [4]=>
  string(6) "Comedy"
}
```

and this is how the result looks like

```
array(3) {
  ["Romance"]=>
  int(2)
  ["Classic"]=>
  int(1)
  ["Comedy"]=>
  int(2)
}
```

This is my array as it currently stands after using `arsort`. As I said, it doesn't matter if I apply `krsort` before hand, the output is the same

```
array(3) {
  ["Romance"]=>
  int(2)
  ["Comedy"]=>
  int(2)
  ["Classic"]=>
  int(1)
}
```

The output that I'm looking for is

```
array(3) {
  ["Comedy"]=>
  int(2)
  ["Romance"]=>
  int(2)
  ["Classic"]=>
  int(1)
}
```

Any ideas on how to achieve this?

**EDIT**

Here is my complete array with functions

```
array(3) {
  ["5 star"]=>
  array(4) {
    [0]=>
    string(7) "Romance"
    [1]=>
    string(7) "Romance"
    [2]=>
    string(6) "Comedy"
    [3]=>
    string(6) "Comedy"
  }
  ["4 star"]=>
  array(5) {
    [0]=>
    string(7) "Romance"
    [1]=>
    string(7) "Romance"
    [2]=>
    string(7) "Classic"
    [3]=>
    string(6) "Comedy"
    [4]=>
    string(6) "Comedy"
  }
  ["3 star"]=>
  array(4) {
    [0]=>
    string(7) "Classic"
    [1]=>
    string(7) "Romance"
    [2]=>
    string(7) "Classic"
    [3]=>
    string(6) "Comedy"
  }
}
```

`$term_list` is the above array

```
foreach ( $term_list as $key=>$value ) {
    echo $key;
    $counted_values = array_count_values($value);
    arsort($counted_values, SORT_NUMERIC);

    foreach ( $counted_values as $counted_values_keys=>$counted_value ) {
        echo '<li>' . $counted_values_keys . ' (' . $counted_value . ') </li>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Sort alphabetically and then sort by value.

Comment: As stated, this doesn't work.

Comment: Duplication? http://stackoverflow.com/q/1673259/3933332

Comment: Why every thing has to duplicate. I dont understand this madness. I upvoted the question. As OP worked hard in my view. Thanks

Comment: This is not a duplicate, he's asking to sort an array numerically and alphabetically with the priority being to numbers.

Comment: Is the data coming from a database?

Comment: @Cups No, it is actually comes from a custom query in Wordpress.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pieter you can use the following code:-

```
$array = array("Romance" =>  2,"Classic" =>  1,"Comedy"  =>  2);
array_multisort(array_values($array), SORT_DESC, array_keys($array), SORT_ASC, $array);
```

This is a duplicate question [PHP array multiple sort - by value then by key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2282013/php-array-multiple-sort-by-value-then-by-key)

The code that I have given was answered by [Jon Bernhardt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/833560/jon-bernhardt).